# Finding a word's frequency in a text file line by line c++

Tags: c++

I need to read a file then ask to user for a word, after that i need to display occurrence of that word line by line. Also I need to check this with char arrays. You can check my 
Output example;

```
Line 2: 1 occurrence(s)
line 4: 2 occurrence(s)
Line 7: 1 occurrence(s)
```

As you can see I divided line lenght by searchString lenght, this is the maximum time of searchString's possiblity of occurrence. So, I need to display occurence(s) but my code shows this division as occurrence. Can you help me about this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;
int number_of_lines = 1;

void numberoflines();

unsigned int GetFileLength(std::string FileName)
{
    std::ifstream InFile(FileName.c_str());
    unsigned int FileLength = 0;
    while (InFile.get() != EOF) FileLength++;
    InFile.close();
    cout<<"Numbers of character in your file : "<<FileLength<<endl;
    return FileLength;
}


int main()
{
    string searchString, fileName, line;
    int a;
    string *b;
    char *c,*d;
    int wordCount = 0, count = 0,count1=0;
    cout << "Enter file name : " << endl;
    cin >> fileName;
    GetFileLength(fileName);
    cout << "Enter a word for searching procces : " << endl;
    cin >> searchString;



    ifstream in (fileName.c_str(), ios::in);
    d= new char[searchString.length()+1];

    strcpy(d,searchString.c_str());

    a=GetFileLength(fileName);
    b= new string [a];


    if(in.is_open()){
        while(!in.eof()){
            getline(in,line);
            c= new char[line.length()+1];
            count++;


            strcpy(c,line.c_str());


            count1=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length()/searchString.length(); i++)
            {

                char *output = NULL;
                output = strstr (c,d);
                if(output) {
                    count1++;
                }
                else count1--;
            }
            if(count1>0){cout<<"Line "<<number_of_lines<<": "<<count1<<" occurrence(s) "<<endl;}
            number_of_lines++;
            if (count==10)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        numberoflines();
    }


    return 0;
}

void numberoflines(){
    number_of_lines--;
    cout<<"number of lines in text file: " << number_of_lines << endl;
}
```

Output:
[image: See the output]

Comment: *I almost did this but my program shows character number of lines* Is unclear to me.  What do you mean by that sentence?

Comment: I'm trying to ignore the memory leaks in this code, but I'm failing horribly.

Comment: @WhozCraig The memory leaks are nothing compared to the method for retrieving the length of the file.

Comment: Why `Also I need to check this with char arrays`. This is C++ use `std::string`

Comment: After you have got it working (not before). Take it to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get some help on better practice.

Comment: Sorry about my english. As you can see I divided line lenght by searchString lenght, this is the maximum time of searchString's possiblity of occurrence. So, I need to display occurence(s) but my code shows this division as occurrence. Sorry about my english, I will make it clear. @NathanOliver

Comment: It would help if you also gave us an example of the input file for your output.

Comment: My project asks me to do that with char array. @LokiAstari

Comment: Why are you calling `strcpy(c, line.c_str())` inside a `for` loop?

Comment: You would use a `for` loop if you were going to copy each character one by one, but you're not doing that.

Comment: You have a confused code using `char *`, `string`, `string*`, all mixed together.  So saying "you must use char arrays" becomes meaningless given all of the differing styles you have in your program.  Also, in reality, this is a 10 or 15 line C++ program, maybe less, if you were actually using C++.

Comment: And to show how your class is cheating you out of learning C++:  http://ideone.com/12D4CZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length()/searchString.length(); i++)
        {
            char *output = NULL;
            output = strstr (c,d);
            if(output) {
                count1++;
            }
            else count1--;
        }
```

is not counting all the matches of the string in the line, because `c` and `d` are the same each time you call `strstr()`. When you repeat the search, you have to start from somewhere after the previous match.

There's also no reason to subtract from `count1` when you don't find a match. You should just exit the loop when that happens. And there's little point in using a `for` loop, because you're not doing anything with `i`; just use a `while` loop.

```
        char *start = c;
        size_t searchlen = searchString.length();
        while (true)
        {
            char *output = strstr (start,d);
            if(output) {
                count1++;
                start = output + searchlen;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much man, I know substracting and for loop for strcpy function has no meaning but I didn't know what to do and tried everything. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read in the entire file into an array or `std::string`.  I recommend you keep this program simple before optimizing.

As noted in your question, you are required to use character arrays and to read line by line.

Look up the [`istream::getline` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) as it will be very useful.

Let's declare a maximum line length of 1024.

Here's the reading file part:

```
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH (1024)
char text_buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH]; // Look, no "new" operator. :-)
//...
while (my_text_file.getline(text_buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, '\n'))
{
 //... TBD
}
```

The above code fragment reads a line of text into the variable `text_buffer`.

Because you are using character arrays, please read through the "str" functions in your favorite texts, such as `strstr`; or you may have to write your own.

The next step would be to extract a "word" from the text line.

In order to extract a word, we need to know where it starts and where it ends.  So, the text line will need to be searched.  See the [`isalpha` funciton](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) as it will be useful.

Here's a loop for finding the beginning and ending of a word:

```
unsigned int word_start_position = 0; // start at beginning of the line.
unsigned int word_end_position = 0;
const unsigned int length = strlen(text_buffer); // Calculate only once.
while (word_start_position < length)
{
  // Find the start of a word.
  while (!isalpha(text_buffer[word_start_position]))
  {
    ++word_start_position;
  }

  // Find end of the word.
  word_end_position = word_start_position;
  while (isalpha(text_buffer[word_end_position]))
  {
    ++word_end_position;
  }
}
```

There some logic issues remaining in the above code fragments for the O.P. to resolve.

The next part would be to add code that uses the start and end position of the word to copy the characters in the word to another variable.   This variable would then be used in a *map* or *associative array* or *dictionary* which contains the number of occurrences.

In other terms, search the container for the word.  If the word exists, increment the associated occurrence variable.  If it doesn't exist, add the word to the container with an occurrence of 1.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! I will keep your advices in my mind thank you again !

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please click on the check mark.